# ajax conditional var before posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a like button.  It shows on each item of an activity feed.  I recently added the ability to like comments as well. Need some help adjusting the ajax to work with this.  I currently grab the closest `.feeditem` and get the id, which is formatted to have the ID of the item.

The comments are showing in the same `.feeditem` div, so clicking like executes the same code, but does not save the right information. Is there a way to make it first check if one of the parent divs id starts with `activity-comment-`  and if it does, have it select different divs, and if its not within that parent id, select the default (below)?

Or if you have a better way to implement this altogether please suggest.  Newer to AJAX so this may not be the most effective way.

```
$likeButton.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
var $itemClicked = $(this)

**//START SELECT**
var liking_user_id = $itemClicked.closest('.feeditem').attr('data-member').match(/\d+/);

var activity_id = $itemClicked.closest('.feeditem').attr('id').match(/\d+/);
**//END SELECT**

var data = {
    'action': 'save_like',
    'activity_id': activity_id,
    'liking_user_id': liking_user_id
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ms_user_actions.ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
            if (!response.success) {
            }
            if (response.data.like == true) {
            $itemClicked.siblings('.feedBox_Likes').text('You Like This!');
            $itemClicked.html('Unlike').attr("like", "unlike");
            }
            if (response.data.unlike == true) {
            $itemClicked.html('Like').attr("unlike", "like");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) in the JQuery API.

Comment: `var matchingParent = $itemClick.closest('[id^="activity-comment"]'); if (matchingParent.length>0){/*has matching ancestor*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to make some assumptions here as there's no HTML in the question. In particular, I'm assuming that you want `liking_user_id` and `activity_id` in both cases, and that these two values are read from the relevant container nodes (divs) in the same way.

If those assumptions are valid, then the easiest approach is probably to devise another class name (eg. 'likeContainer') and apply it to the outer (feeditem) container and each of the inner comment containers. This class name will be additional to any existing class names, eg `<div class="feeditem likeContainer">`

The jQuery would then be as follows :

```
var liking_user_id = $itemClicked.closest('.likeContainer').attr('data-member').match(/\d+/);
var activity_id = $itemClicked.closest('.likeContainer').attr('id').match(/\d+/);
```

Thus,

- when a comment's 'like' is clicked, `.closest()` will find an inner, comment container
- when a non-comment's 'like' is clicked, `.closest()` will find an outer, feeditem container.

If the assumptions are not valid, then you might consider building the outer and inner divs differently. This might be the line of least resistance.